# Primefaces menubar style is broken on IE 8

Tags: internet-explorer, jsf-2, primefaces, myfaces

I have a simple menuBar in my application and works very nice on chrome and firefox. But, when I tested with IE 8, the style of menubar is broken. I think is just style because the links are working fine. Below, a screenshot of my menu on IE 8: 
[image: MenuBar on my IE 8]

And my menubar code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
      xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">

    <ui:composition>
        <h:form id="menuForm">
            <p:menubar id="appMenu">
               <p:menuitem value="Celulares" url="#{menuMB.toMeusCelularesIndex()}" rendered="#{p:ifAnyGranted('USER')}" />

                <p:submenu label="Celulares (Admin)" rendered="#{p:ifAnyGranted('ADMIN')}">
                    <p:menuitem value="Titulares" url="#{menuMB.toCelularTitularIndex()}" rendered="#{p:ifAnyGranted('ADMIN')}" />
                    <p:menuitem value="Agregados" url="#{menuMB.toCelularAgregadoIndex()}" rendered="#{p:ifAnyGranted('ADMIN')}" />
                </p:submenu>

                <p:submenu label="Faturas" rendered="#{p:ifAnyGranted('ADMIN')}">
                    <p:menuitem value="Titulares" url="#{menuMB.toFaturaTitularIndex()}" rendered="#{p:ifAnyGranted('ADMIN')}" />
                    <p:menuitem value="Agregados" url="#{menuMB.toFaturaAgregadoIndex()}" rendered="#{p:ifAnyGranted('ADMIN')}" />
                </p:submenu>

                <p:submenu label="Sistema" rendered="#{p:ifAnyGranted('ADMIN')}">
                    <p:menuitem value="Forçar Login" url="#{menuMB.toForcarLogin()}" rendered="#{p:ifAnyGranted('ADMIN')}"/>
                    <p:menuitem value="Fazer Checkup" url="#" rendered="#{p:ifAnyGranted('ADMIN')}" />
                    <p:menuitem value="Administradores" url="#{menuMB.toAdministradores()}" rendered="#{p:ifAnyGranted('ADMIN')}" />
                    <p:menuitem value="Parâmetros do Sistema" url="#{menuMB.toParametrosIndex()}" rendered="#{p:ifAnyGranted('ADMIN')}" />
                </p:submenu>

                <p:menuitem value="Sair" url="#{menuMB.toLogout()}" rendered="#{p:ifAnyGranted('USER')}" />
            </p:menubar>
        </h:form>
    </ui:composition>
</html>
```

I accessed the [menubar showcase](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/menubar.jsf), and it works on IE 8. I can only imagine that I've made some mistake on my code. I am currently using:

- Primefaces 4.0,
- MyFaces 2.1.12
- Tomcat 7.0.42.

If you need more information, please let me know.

Comment: Check your developer tools in IE8 when you open your website where style broken and `Primefaces showcase` and check for `document mode` and `browser mode`in two cases.See you find any differences when you load two websites.

Comment: Thanks, @SRy! That's it. I changed Compatibility Mode to IE8, and it worked. I barely use IE and I didn't even know about this compatibility mode. Do you know how can I transform your comment to the answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your developer tools in IE8 when you `open your website where style broken` and `Primefaces showcase` and check for document mode and browser mode in two cases.See you find any differences when you load two websites. Check out these links to know more about this behavior

> http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/ie/en-US/afb57ce6-d149-4a09-8811-63c0645c92e6/force-ie8-to-render-in-ie8-standard-mode?forum=iewebdevelopment

This link tells how to force IE8 to open in the mode which does not break your `CSS` programmatically by specifying in your `XHTML` file

> http://blog.primefaces.org/?p=1433